# How to show files from a folder on sdcard in android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have created a folder on sdcard for storing different type of files.

Now, i just need to show all file on click of application icon.

Can anyone provide me correct source code for this ?

Its urgent !!

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Look up on google, how to create a file manager :P

Answer (score 0):

do you just want a list?

```
File directory = getMyDirectory(); // do this however you want
File[] files = directory.listFiles(); // gets an array of files in the dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void directoryPath(File path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                //you can do what you want here
            }
        }
    }
```

the above code give all the files in the folder...